# Draw colored dots in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drawing, draw

i saw this in a angularJS App:

[image: dots]

Maybe he's drawing borders?? Any ideas how i could do this properly? 
The color should be changeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6w5D4RGTDOorYqhQMk8N?p=preview) where you can change the color of the dot with ngStyle, please take a look at it.

Using ngStyle you can also change the background-color within a controller.

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="">
  <input type="button" value="change color to blue" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'blue'}">
  <input type="button" value="change color to red" ng-click="myStyle={'background-color':'red'}">
  <div class="circle" ng-style="myStyle"></div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
.circle {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```